# Cómo puedo cambiar la forma en la que se muestra la información al leer de un fichero

Tags: java

Quiero leer un fichero en java y mostrar la información del fichero por consola de la forma que se indica en la última imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo de codigo

```
package Ejercicio07;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ejercicio07 {
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

File fichero = new File("C:/Prueba/ejercicio07.txt");   

public void menu() {
    int opcion = 0;
    while(opcion != 3) {
        System.out.println("(1) Introducir datos nuevos: \r\n(2) Leer datos del archivo \r\n(3) Salir del programa");
        opcion = sc.nextInt();
        if(opcion == 1) {
            introducirDatos();
        }else if(opcion == 2) {
            leerFicheros();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Has salido del programa");
        }           
    }
}

public void introducirDatos() {
    try {
        FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(fichero, true);
        escribir.write("Numeros: " +"\r\n");
        int suma = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            suma += num;
            escribir.write(num + "\r\n");
        }
        escribir.write("Suma: " + suma + "\r\nMedia: " + ((double)suma/5) + "\r\n");
        escribir.close();
        System.out.println("Has terminado de introducir numeros");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error al escribir en el fichero");
    }

}

public void leerFicheros() {
    try {
        FileReader leer = new FileReader(fichero);

        int c = 0;

        while(c != -1) {

            c = leer.read();

            if(c != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) + c);
            }
        }

        leer.close();
        System.out.println("Has terminado de leer los numeros");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error al leer en el fichero");
    }
}

}
```

La informacion esta de esta forma en el fichero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola  la duda es sobre como imprimir la información, cómo recogerla o ambas cosas ?

Comment: Como imprimir(mostrarla por consola)la informacion de la forma que me piden.

Comment: Te bastará con adaptar una de las respuestas ya dadas y listo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo el código recién hecho para que veas que con pocas líneas y teniendo el archivo de texto 'ejercicio07.txt' dentro de nuestro proyecto, tal cual lo tienes tú, con esa información, te lee cada una de las líneas, hasta que ya no tiene nada que leer, osea la información es nula o no existe.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Ejercicio07 {

    private static void muestraContenido(String archivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String cadena;
        FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        while((cadena = b.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(cadena);
        b.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        muestraContenido("ejercicio07.txt");
    }
}
```

//Sigo por aquí. También pienso que lo suyo es tener un archivo con solo números para leer esos números y poder manipular la información recibida de ese archivo sabiendo que son números, y luego hacer las operaciones que creas conveniente y guardarlo en otro archivo, por ejemplo.
Otra forma es guardar toda la información recibida de la cadena es guardarla en un array de char, y luego con un condicional if verificar si el char recibido es número, y ahí haces las operaciones oportunas.

Answer (score 0):

aquí te dejo las fos formas de imprimirlo, muy similar a como ya te ha mostrado Diego, aunque incluyendo ambas formas

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {3, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9,11,16};
    forma1(nums);
    System.out.println();
    forma2(nums);
}


private static void forma1(int[] nums){
    System.out.println("Números:");
    int suma = 0;
    for (int num : nums) {
        System.out.printf("%d%n", num);
        suma += num;
    }
    System.out.println("Suma: " + suma);
    double promedio = suma / nums.length;
    System.out.printf("Media: %s", promedio);
}

    private static void forma2(int[] nums){
    int suma = 0;
    double promedio = 0;
    System.out.print("Los "+nums.length+" números son:");
    for (int num : nums) {
        System.out.print(" "+num);
        suma += num;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Suma: " + suma);
    promedio = suma / nums.length;
    System.out.printf("Media: %s", promedio);
}
```